# What does this SQL query do? Please explain

Tags: sql

What means this query?

```
@numberx = @numberx -1
UPDATE  th
SET     @numberX= numberY= @numberX + 1
FROM    Table1 th
INNER JOIN Table2 td ON th.Id = td.idth
WHERE   td.anything = @anything
```

At line 3, what is this "double equality"?
And what is this "from" and  "inner" on an UPDATE?

Comment: You should read this excellent article on [understanding joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a multiple table update for assigning consecutive numbers to each row in `Table1` where the corresponding row in `Table2` has a specific value for the column `anything`.

For each matching row it sets the column `numberY` to the value of `@numberX + 1`. It also reassigns that value back to `@numberX`, which causes `@numberX` to be incremented for each row.

This is known as a "quirky update". It is an undocumented and not guaranteed approach to generate running totals. In 2012 `SUM() OVER (ORDER BY ...)` should be used instead.

Comment: Is that a row-by-row incremental update, or will all numberY values receive the same increment?  (that almost came out in english...)

Comment: Is this guaranteed to work in SQL Server?  I see no reason why the update should be serialized by the presence of a variable.

Comment: @MarkByers - What RDBMS supports this?

Comment: It's definitely not MySQL. MySQL uses a different syntax for multiple table updates. Looks like SQL Server to me.

Comment: It's a correct format for SQL server but the keyword "SET" is missing before "@numberx = @numberx -1"

Comment: Thank you, Andy and everybody! Explanation exceptional!